# except OSError as (errcode , message): SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, syntax-error, ose

hello everyone this is the review library from python and i got an error from the build in library which is only syntax error

```
except OSError as (errcode , message):
```

this is the line which though outs the error but since i don't have much experience

with try and capture exceptions so what shall i do

my python is 3.6 but it seems this library build with 2.7 how to solve it

and when i run it it gives me this syntax error

> ```
> except OSError as (errcode , message):  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following;

```
try:
    # code that raises OSError
    ...
    ...
except OSError as e:
    print('Error! Code: {c}, Message, {m}'.format(c = type(e).__name__, m = str(e)))
```

Comment: except OSError as ([errcode] , [message]):                                                                                    
      if errcode != errno.ENOENT: 
        raise

Comment: it is written like that

Comment: where is it written?

Comment: it worked your solution but i got another thing which is import error:ModuleNotFoundError

Answer (score 0):

This is a Python 2 / Python 3 incompatibility.

The following is syntactically correct and works as one would expect in Python 2.7, but not in Python 3.

```py
try:
    raise OSError(42, "don't panic")
except OSError as (errcode, message):
    print("errcode:", errcode, "message:", message)
```

The incompatibility is described for example in https://portingguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/exceptions.html#iterating-exceptions.

So, to obtain something that works in Python 2 as well as Python 3, you'd have to unpack the arguments yourself.

```py
try:
    raise OSError(42, "don't panic")
except OSError as e:
    errcode, message = e.args
    print("errcode:", errcode, "message:", message)
```